# How to turn only HDD back to basic after accidentally creating 5th partition?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

I was trying to create a separate partition for use with an ISO image on USB drive as it was a Linux program. I succeeded, along with turning my only drive from basic into dynamic. It has my Windows 7 OS / boot files everything, it is my main :C drive. How can I merge the 6GB partition back into C:, and will EaseUS Partition Master version let me safely convert it back to basic afterwards?

I cant turn off my laptop and I'm afraid to even put it in standby mode as I know I won't be able to boot Windows back up.

[image: Link to first Image]

[image: link to image2]

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Back up all volumes on the disk you want to convert from dynamic to basic.
>
> 2.Open a command prompt and type `diskpart`.
>
> 3.At the DISKPART prompt, type `list disk`. Make note of the disk number you want to convert to basic.
>
> 4.At the DISKPART prompt, type `select disk <disknumber>`.
>
> 5.At the DISKPART prompt, type `detail disk <disknumber>`.
>
> 6.For each volume on the disk, at the DISKPART prompt, type `select volume= <volumenumber>` and then type `delete volume`.
>
> 7.At the DISKPART prompt, type `select disk <disknumber>`. Specify the disk number of the disk that you want to convert to a basic disk.
>
> 8.At the DISKPART prompt, type `convert basic`.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238(v=ws.11).aspx)